# Scrolling breaks in uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am having a problem viewing my tableview when i get the data of my cells from a server. If i do not use photos there is no breaks in the scrolling, but i want to use the images also. Can anyone knows how can i resolve this? I am getting the data from a plist in my server.

Here is the code of the image that makes the scrolling breaks (i am using custom style cell)

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];




    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageName"]];

    NSData *URLData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];



    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:URLData];

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    imgView.image = img;

....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"?

Comment: When i scroll down and up the scroll make a small break and then scroll. If i comment the image and there is no image that does not happen.

Comment: check the answer from @JimmyLee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the scrolling stops and starts, this might be because if the images are loaded from a server (which might take a noticeable amount of time to do), executing on the main thread causes freezing.

If this is the case, the fix is to fetch the images in another thread. Fortunately iOS has a fairly easy to use multithreading system called Grand Central Dispatch.

Here's some example code:

```
    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create("FetchImage", NULL);
    dispatch_async(q, ^{
        /* Fetch the image from the server... */
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            /* This is the main thread again, where we set the tableView's image to
               be what we just fetched. */
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you help me how can i implement that in my code? I tried diferent ways but maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest putting the lines where you make the NSURL, NSData, and UIImage into the `/* Fetch the image...` portion, then put the code that actually sets the cell's picture in the `/* This is the main thread...` portion. All of this should go inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: I put this and did not worked. the NSURL, NSDARA and UIImage in the fetch... and the UIImageView and imgView.image in this is the main..

Comment: Is it the same problem as before? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "break", so I'm not wholly sure what the issue is.

Comment: Now the image does not appear.

Comment: I put the code right above the line cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: I'm sorry, it's kinda hard to see what's going on without the actual code. Maybe you should try to learn a little bit more about Grand Central Dispatch, or open a new question if you want to learn about specific functionality.